# WCF file-less activation with no configuration

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I need to configure WCF services using file-less activation through code and without the need to add factories under serviceActivations in web.config.

Does anyone have an idea as to if this is possible or how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on .NET 4, you could use the `ServiceRoute` as an alternative, which can be setup totally in code.

See Ron Jacobs' two excellent posts on the topic:

- [Using System.Web.Routing with Data Services (OData)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2010/04/05/using-system-web-routing-with-data-services-odata.aspx)
- [WCF Data Services and ServiceRoute](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2010/04/06/wcf-data-services-and-serviceroute.aspx)

This also works with regular services - not just OData services. Just replace the `DataServiceHostFactory` in Ron's example with either a regular `ServiceHostFactory` (for SOAP services) or the `WebServiceHostFactory` (for REST-oriented WCF services)

Comment: First answer, short useful and correct. When was the last time I came across such thing! Thanks Marc

Comment: Unfortunately this only works with aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" - in other words only for http based bindings. How could I do that with net.tcp?